Why are files left after "git lfs prune", of commits which don't exist anymore?
I just removed a branch und checked using git for-each-ref that all references to it are gone. I also verified that it is not merged in any branch which is still here:
$ git for-each-ref
a768c5e4e978cc03ed8f62bd404c93009ff7655a commit refs/heads/master
aec5aa23a9a12990c746089f21c61e55c00f8594 commit refs/heads/base
a768c5e4e978cc03ed8f62bd404c93009ff7655a commit refs/remotes/origin/master
aec5aa23a9a12990c746089f21c61e55c00f8594 commit refs/remotes/origin/base

However, I still can see local LFS files which are referenced by commits which don't exist in any still-existing reference (the last three)
$ git lfs ls-files -a
a839e89bd8 * build/file1.apk
0774f8e633 * download/file2.apk
883b3e9b7a - build/file624.zip
4b3650cb0b - download/file413.zip
16dfaf2af3 - build/file845.zip

I tried to prune them using the following commands:
git lfs prune 
git lfs prune --recent

But the files don't go away.
Interesting: I already called a bunch of git gc and git repack variations and the shown commits don't exist anymore locally:
$ git show 883b3e9b7a
fatal: ambiguous argument '883b3e9b7a': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

So, why is LFS not removing these files and how can I remove them?
PS: the real use case is much bigger and there are hundreds of files which should be removed. So it's about saving space (locally).
